# Обратиться к методу класса из HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ооп

Имеется класс User. У него есть два свойства. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "Добавить значение" в выпадающий список добавлялся новый экземпляр класса(в самом списке должен быть массив этих экземпляров).
JS:

```
var Users=new Array();
class User{
    constructor(text,option){
        this.text=text;
        this.option=option;
    }
    Add(){
        alert('Работает');
        var str=document.form.textarea.value;
        alert(str);
        var properties=new Array();
        properties=str.Split(',');
        alert(properties);
        var User=new User(properties[0],properties[1]);
        Users.push(User);
        UsersList.append(User);
        User.selected = true;
    }

    
}
```

HTML:

```
<form class="form">
        <input name="textarea" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" placeholder="Поле1"></textarea> 
        <select id="UsersList">
            <option disabled>Список объектов</option>
        </select>
        <p><input type="button" value="Добавить значение" onclick="Add()"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Пермешать"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Вывести свойство"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Вывести массив"></p>
        <!-- <input class="form__btn" type="button" onclick="Sum()" value="Добавить значения"> -->

</form>
```

Текст задания:
Реализовать с помощью классов JS:
●   Создайте на странице в форме 2 поля: текстовое, выпадающий список;
●   Добавьте 4 кнопки под этими полями:
○   Добавить значения
○   Перемешать
○   Вывести свойство
○   Вывести массив
●   При клике на “добавить значения”, введенные пользователем данные, добавьте в объект в соответствующие свойства:
○   text
○   option
Этот объект добавьте в общий массив, где будут хранится все вводимые значения, после чего очистите поля формы;
●   При клике на перемешать, (внезапно) перемешать массив объектов.
●   При клике на “Вывести свойство” вывести в консоль свойство option последнего объекта в массиве;
●   При клике на “Вывести массив”... вывести массив в консоль . - здесь сложного ничего нет, выполнении данного пункта на ваше усмотрение, однако он был бы вам удобен для отладки и проверки работы скрипта.

Comment: Экземпляр класса может быть добавлен в список только в том случае, если этот класс наследует HtmlElement. Вы, скорее всего, хотите добавить не экземпляр класса, а какое-то из его свойств (имя? id?)

Comment: ● При клике на “добавить значения”, введенные пользователем данные, добавьте в объект в соответствующие свойства:
○ text
○ option
Этот объект добавьте в общий массив, где будут хранится все вводимые значения, после чего очистите поля формы;

Comment: Про список тут ничего не написано

Comment: Метод Add должен быть объявлен вне класса, как отдельная функция

Comment: Про класс тоже кстати ничего не написано

Comment: ● Создайте на странице в форме 2 поля: текстовое, выпадающий список;
● Добавьте 4 кнопки под этими полями:
○ Добавить значения
○ Перемешать
○ Вывести свойство 
○ Вывести массив
● При клике на “добавить значения”, введенные пользователем данные, добавьте в объект в соответствующие свойства:
○ text
○ option
Этот объект добавьте в общий массив, где будут хранится все вводимые значения, после чего очистите поля формы;
● При клике на перемешать, (внезапно) перемешать массив объектов. 
● При клике на “Вывести свойство” вывести в консоль свойство option последнего объекта в массиве;

Comment: ● При клике на “Вывести массив”... вывести массив в консоль . - здесь сложного ничего нет, выполнении данного пункта на ваше усмотрение, однако он был бы вам удобен для отладки и проверки работы скрипта.

Comment: Так выглядит полное задание, в моем понимание это было так: создается экземпляр класса при нажатии на кнопку, в выпадающем списке выводятся свойства по типу: СвойствоЭкземпляра1,СвойствоЭкземпляра2. Если это не так, то тогда зачем нужен выпадающий список?

Comment: Список - для опций. Вы оттуда должны выбирать option, а из текстового поля - текст. Класс вам не нужен. Добавлять в список тоже ничего не надо. Нужно изначально его заполнить опциями

Comment: Нужен. В начале задания просто еще написано, что реализовать на основе класса

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный текст задания. Т.к. вы попытались решить самостоятельно - вопрос не закроют

Comment: Полный текст задания добавлен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, давайте по порядку

```js
var Users = new Array(); 
// Дело вкуса, но я бы тут написал const users = [];

// Класс здесь не нужен, можно обойтись стандартным классом Object. 
// Но если в задании так написано - можно и класс.
class User{
    constructor(text,option){
        this.text=text;
        this.option=option;
    }
}

// В качестве метода класса вы не сможете вызвать эту функцию по onclick, 
// т.к. для этого нужен либо экземпляр класса, либо сделать этот метод static 
// - в любом случае нужно обращение к User.
// Короче, как написал @Alexander Chernin - это должна быть отдельная функция.
function Add(){
    // alert('Работает');
    console.log('Тоже работает и не надо нажимать ОК');
    
    // var str=document.form.textarea.value; 
    // document.form не существует. Есть document.forms, 
    // можно обратиться к вашей форме document.forms[0], 
    // но лучше использовать селектор:
    const form = document.querySelector('.form');

    const str=form.textarea.value; 
    console.log(str);
    
    // Я всё же считаю, что вы не совсем верно поняли задание 
    // и список - это не список пользователей, а список опций
    var option=form.optionslist.value;
    console.log(option);
    
    // var User= new User(str, option);
    // При таком объявлении с помощью var вы затираете 
    // в данной области видимости имя "User", 
    // которым у вас назывался ваш класс
    //  и на этой строчке (и внутри этой функции в целом с самого начала)
    // у вас User уже переменная без значения. (гуглить hoisting)
    
    const user = new User (str, option);
    // Это не обязательно, но среди разработчиков принято 
    // именовать классы с большой буквы, а экземпляры - с маленькой.
    // В данном случае решает вышеописанную проблему
    
    // В этой строчке всё было хорошо)
    Users.push(user);
    
    // Очистка формы
    form.textarea.value = "";
    form.optionslist.options[0].selected = true;
}


function printArray(){
  console.log(Users);
}

// Функции перемешивания массива и выведения свойства я оставил вам
```

```html
<form class="form">
        <!-- onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" нет такой функции -->
        <input name="textarea" placeholder="Поле1">
        <!-- 
        </textarea> 
        Вы закрываете тег textarea, который не был открыт. input name= textarea - это не textarea, это другой тег и его не надо закрывать.
        --> 
        <select id="UsersList" name="optionslist">
            <!-- Судя по заданию, здесь всё же нужны заранее заготовленные опции -->
            <option value="" disabled selected>Список опций</option>
            <option value="Option 1">Опция 1</option>
            <option value="Option 2">Опция 2</option>
        </select>
        <p><input type="button" value="Добавить значение" onclick="Add()" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Пермешать"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Вывести свойство"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Вывести массив" onclick="printArray()"></p>

</form>
```

Comment: Благодарю за код и за важные комментарии. Пришлось только исправить у остальных кнопок тип на button, а то иначе массив обновляется и становится пустым. А остальное все хорошо работает)Спасибо)

Comment: @Buterok Странно, это не должно быть никак связано с типом кнопок..

Comment: @Buterok а, да, я понял. submit отправляет форму, и когда вы нажимаете на эту кнопку у вас перезагружается страница. В данном случае вы верно поступили - кнопки, которые не должны отправлять форму, не должны быть submit. Но если, например, вам нужно отправить форму AJAXом, то это лечится навешиванием обработчика onsubmit с return false внутри.